# Transmit two arrays with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework

I want to transmit two arrays with angular to my play framework(2.4) application.

This is what I have.
inP and outP are arrays

```
$http({
        url: $scope.appUrl + 'networkInsertJson',
        method: "POST",
        data: angular.toJson($scope.inP, $scope.outP),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
})
```

How I can transmit two arrays with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$http({
    url: $scope.appUrl + 'networkInsertJson',
    method: "POST",
    data: angular.toJson({ in: $scope.inP, out:  $scope.outP}),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
 })
```

`angular.toJson(obj, pretty);` Takes two arguements, one to convert to Json and the other is a flag, if it should prettify it or not.

Check with the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

If you want to send two values, wrap them in an object. That way you can send both at the same time.